# What is the reason choosing arbitrary incoming/outgoing conventions of particles in a Feynman diagram work?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, conventions, feynman-diagrams, antimatter

Lets consider any specific Feynman diagram for the process $A(p_1)+B(p_2)\rightarrow C(p_3)+D(p_4)$, where $p_1, p_2$ are the ingoing momenta and $p_3, p_4$ are the outgoing momenta.
As I have now learned, it is okay to swap the momenta $p_3$ and $p_4$ in such a way, that they are being handled as ingoing, which is done by defining $p_3, p_4$ as negative 4-vectors in the succeeding calculations. This "all-ingoing" convention then returns an identical amplitude for this diagram and then obviously the same cross-section etc.

The same thing can also be observed at using some Feynman rules which are based on an "all-ingoing" convention. If you want to have some momenta as outgoing, you have to define them as a negative 4-vector in the Feynman rule.

My question then is: Why is that okay in general? How does that work with the first energy component of the 4-momentum vector? Do we just always assume positive energy within the calculation independent of the incoming/outgoing choice? If we just swap the momentum direction, wouldn't it be more logical to just change from covariant to contravariant or vice versa?